# Filter out groups with a length equal to one

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I am creating a `groupby` object from a Pandas `DataFrame` and want to select out all the groups with > 1 size.

Example:

```
     A  B
0  foo  0
1  bar  1
2  foo  2
3  foo  3
```

The following doesn't seem to work:

```
grouped = df.groupby('A')
grouped[grouped.size > 1]
```

Expected Result:

```
A
foo 0
    2
    3
```

Comment: give us a concrete example, and show what you have tried.

Comment: Hopefully some help: `grouped.size().apply(lambda x: x>1)`, but I'm not sure how to do this

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/919

Comment: this is interesting ..for a change I have hit a area where a feature needed by me is missing in Pandas ..for long it was my understanding of it that was missing ..great library for what I do..

Answer (score 50):

As of pandas 0.12 you can do:

```
>>> grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)

     A  B
0  foo  0
2  foo  2
3  foo  3
```

Comment: What is the 'x' in this case? Does that refer to the column which you used to groupby?

Comment: `x` would be each subgroup of the groupby operation, which you can examine with `grouped.groups`. In case of a multicolumn groupby these subgroups refer to several columns, but this is irrelevant as `len` counts by the rows in pandas objects.

Comment: Is there a way to get GroupBy object after filter, not a DataFrame? The only way I see now is to call groupby again, but this seems inefficient

Comment: @IvanVirabyan Worse, with categorical values the empty groups pop up again.

Comment: `grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x.index) > 1)` should be slightly faster

Answer (score 18):

I have found `transform` to be much more efficient than `filter` for very large dataframes:

```
element_group_sizes = df['A'].groupby(df['A']).transform('size')
df[element_group_sizes>1]
```

Or, in one line:

```
df[df['A'].groupby(df['A']).transform('size')>1]
```

Comment: Great answer! Only you paid attention to efficiency. Bravo!

Comment: Shouldn't be `element_group_sizes = df['A'].groupby('A')['A'].transform('size')` instead?

Comment: @IgorFobia no -- `df['A']` will be a Series and will no longer have a column `'A'`. I suppose `element_group_sizes = df.groupby('A')['A'].transform('size')` would work though.

Answer (score 7):

If you still need a workaround:

```
In [49]: pd.concat([group for _, group in grouped if len(group) > 1])
Out[49]: 
     A  B
0  foo  0
2  foo  2
3  foo  3
```

Comment: :Thanks :  thats what I had implemented now but it would be nice to know how to do filtering on grouped objects coz that would be independent of writing a new list comprehension for each custom filtering case.

Comment: The issue #919 cited above would be a good solution once someone implements it

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df[df['A'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```