# How to filter based on a boolean in a column and return a groupby obj

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return a groupby object that contains only items with 3 or more entries for the field I am grouping on. For instance, if I have the following object and I group on `'Letters'`:

```
Letters Numbers Items Bool
A       1       lamp  1
B       2       glass 1
B       2       table 1
C       5       pic   0
B       3       glass 0
C       4       bottle 1
C       2       horse 0
```

Then my code would only return a groupby object with b

I have tried the following:

```
old_df = a_df.groupby('Letters')
new_df = old_df.filter(len(old_df['Letters'])>2)
```

I've also tried with some lambda stuff mentioned here: [filtering grouped df in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167391/filtering-grouped-df-in-pandas)

Thanks!

---

So if I wanted to return a vector with the sum of all the values in Bool per letter where the number of entries per letter exceeds three, how would I do it? With the data provided, this would be [2,1] (2 for B and 1 for C)

Comment: Amended, sorry! Didn't mean to say 'a'

Comment: I think you mean "exceeds or is equal to three"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the output of `groupby`:

```
In [4]: df
Out[4]:
  Letters  Numbers  Items  Bool
0       A        1   lamp     1
1       B        2  glass     1
2       B        2  table     1
3       C        5    pic     0
4       B        3  glass     0

In [6]: df.groupby('Letters').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2)
Out[6]:
  Letters  Numbers  Items  Bool
1       B        2  glass     1
2       B        2  table     1
4       B        3  glass     0
```

The object that results from a `groupby` operation is an iterable object, and its "iterands" are `tuple`s of the group label and the subset of the original `DataFrame` corresponding to the group. For example,

```
In [9]: for name, subset in df.groupby('Letters'):
   ...:     print(name)
   ...:     print(subset)
   ...:     print('\n')
   ...:
A
  Letters  Numbers Items  Bool
0       A        1  lamp     1


B
  Letters  Numbers  Items  Bool
1       B        2  glass     1
2       B        2  table     1
4       B        3  glass     0


C
  Letters  Numbers Items  Bool
3       C        5   pic     0
```

To sum the values of `Bool` by `Letter` where the number of members in each group is greater than 2:

```
In [39]: df.groupby('Letters').filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2).groupby('Letters').Bool.sum()
Out[39]:
Letters
B          2
C          1
Name: Bool, dtype: int64
```

Comment: See section added at the bottom of question. Thanks though, this has been helpful and I was definitely misunderstanding.

Comment: And how do you filter? When I try to filter, it doesn't return a groupby obj so that doesn't work for me...again thanks for the help!!! I've been trying to use the documentation...http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html