# Filtering grouped df in Dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Related to this similar question for Pandas: [filtering grouped df in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13167391/filtering-grouped-df-in-pandas)

**Action**
To eliminate groups based on an expression applied to a different column than the groupby column.

**Problem**
Filter is not implemented for grouped dataframes.

**Tried**
Groupby and apply to eliminate certain groups, which returns an index error because the apply function is supposed to always return something?

```
In [16]:
def filter_empty(df):
    if not df.label.values.all(4):
        return df

df_nonempty = df_norm.groupby('hash').apply(filter_empty, meta=meta)

In [17]:
len(df_nonempty.hash.unique())
...

<ipython-input-16-6da6d9b6c069> in filter_empty()
      1 def filter_empty(df):
----> 2     if not df.label.values.all(4):
      3         return df
      4 
      5 df_nonempty = df_norm.groupby('hash').apply(filter_empty, meta=meta)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _all()
     39 
     40 def _all(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 41     return umr_all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     42 
     43 def _count_reduce_items(arr, axis):

ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

**Question**
Is there another way to achieve the Dask equivalent of Pandas `grouped.filter(lambda x: len(x) > 1)` ? Or the groupby apply simply implemented wrongly?

**Example**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

In [3]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aacaaa'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbc')})
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

In [8]:
df.A.unique().compute()
Out[8]:
0    a
1    c
Name: A, dtype: object

In [6]:
def filter_4(df):
    if not df.B.values.all(4):
        return df

df_notalla = df.groupby('A').apply(filter_4, meta=df)

In [10]:
df_notall4.A.unique().compute()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-894a491faa57> in <module>()
----> 1 df_notalla.A.unique().compute()

...

<ipython-input-6-ef10326ae42a> in filter_4(df)
      1 def filter_4(df):
----> 2     if not df.B.values.all(4):
      3         return df
      4 
      5 df_notalla = df.groupby('A').apply(filter_4, meta=df)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     39 
     40 def _all(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 41     return umr_all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     42 
     43 def _count_reduce_items(arr, axis):

ValueError: 'axis' entry is out of bounds
```

Comment: Did you try to reset_index() of your groupby and then filter the dask dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) first, then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for `Series` (it is like [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), but not implemented in `dask` too) and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('aacaaa'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbc')})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  a  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  a  5  4  7  9  b
4  a  5  2  1  2  b
5  a  4  3  0  4  c
```

---

```
a = df.groupby('F')['A'].size()
print (a)
F
a    3
b    2
c    1
Name: A, dtype: int64

s = df['F'].map(a)
print (s)
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    2
4    2
5    1
Name: F, dtype: int64

df = df[s > 1]
print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  a  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  a  5  4  7  9  b
4  a  5  2  1  2  b
```

EDIT:

I think here is not necessary `groupby`:

```
df_notall4 = df[df.C != 4].drop_duplicates(subset=['A','D'])['D'].compute()
```

But if really need it:

```
def filter_4(x):
        return x[x.C != 4]

df_notall4 = df.groupby('A').apply(filter_4, meta=df).D.unique().compute()
print (df_notall4)
0    1
1    3
2    0
3    5
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: This is very useful, if you would filter based on size (as in the reference question I provided). However would you also know how to apply this for other expressions. Like; - pseudo - `eliminate group if group.label.values.all(4)`

Comment: Hmmm, can you add some sample? because not sure if understand `group.label.values.all(4)` - especially `4`.

Comment: Thanks for the help @jezrael! I added an example

Comment: problem is in `4`, you cannot use it. Do you need - `df.B.values.all()` ?

Comment: Can you add desired output? Because `if not df.B.values.all(4)` is wrong.

Comment: I added the desired output to my current solution, please let me know if you have any remarks to this solution.

Comment: That is absolutely a better answer than mine. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does anyone know how to map the results back to the dataframe for a multi-column groupby? I've posted a question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682524/dask-filter-dataframe-on-multi-column-groupby-size

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jezrael I reviewed my implementation and created the following solution (see my provided example).

```
df_notall4 = []
for d in list(df[df.C != 4].D.unique().compute()):
    df_notall4.append(df.groupby('D').get_group(d))

df_notall4 = dd.concat(df_notall4, interleave_partitions=True)
```

Which results in

```
In [8]:
df_notall4.D.unique().compute()
Out[8]:
0    1
1    3
2    5
3    0
Name: D, dtype: object
```