# Dask Filter Dataframe on Multi-Column Groupby Size

Tags: python, pandas, dask

Goal = Multi-column groupby a dask dataframe, and filter out groups that contain less than 3 rows.

Based on this post: 
[Filtering grouped df in Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46927174/filtering-grouped-df-in-dask)

I'm able to calculate the size of each groupby object, but I cannot figure out how to map it back to my dataframe from the mutli-column groupby. I tried many variations of the following to no avail:

```
a = input_df.groupby(["FeatureID", "region"])["Target"].size()
s = input_df[["FeatureID", "region"]].map(a)
```

It works great for a single column groupby.

### Solution

Thanks to @jezrael I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
a = input_df.groupby(["FeatureID", "region"])["Target"].nunique().to_frame("feature_div")
input_df = input_df.join(a, on=["FeatureID", "region"])

# filter out features below diversity threshold
diversified = input_df[input_df.feature_div >= diversity_threshold]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `join` with `to_frame`:

```
a = input_df.groupby(["FeatureID", "region"])["Target"].size().to_frame('New')
input_df = input_df.join(a, on=["FeatureID", "region"])
```

**Sample**:

```
import pandas as pd
from dask import dataframe as dd 

input_df = pd.DataFrame({
         'FeatureID':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'region':list('aaabbb'),
         'Target':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
})

print (input_df)
   FeatureID region  Target
0          4      a       7
1          5      a       8
2          4      a       9
3          5      b       4
4          5      b       2
5          4      b       3
```

---

```
sd = dd.from_pandas(input_df, npartitions=3)
print (sd)
              FeatureID  region Target
npartitions=3                         
0                 int64  object  int64
2                   ...     ...    ...
4                   ...     ...    ...
5                   ...     ...    ...
Dask Name: from_pandas, 3 tasks

a = sd.groupby(["FeatureID", "region"])["Target"].size().to_frame('New')
out = sd.join(a, on=["FeatureID", "region"]).compute()
print (out)
   FeatureID region  Target  New
0          4      a       7    2
1          5      a       8    1
2          4      a       9    2
3          5      b       4    2
4          5      b       2    2
5          4      b       3    1
```